# How to use `docker volume prune`? (`docker volume prune` removing all volumes even when container is running)

Tags: docker, docker-volume

On the docker documentation, it says the following:

> `docker volume prune` === Remove all unused local volumes

To test that, I've set up a MongoDb container with the official latest image from docker hub. Doing so, created 2 volumes behind the scenes which are probably needed by the container to store the data.

When running `docker volume ls` now, I can see the two volumes with random names.

So let's say I would have multiple containers with volumes using random names. Now it would get difficult to know which of these are still in use and so I was expecting `docker volume prune` to help out here.

So I executed the command, expecting `docker volume prune` to delete nothing as my container is up and running with MongoDb.
But what actually happened, is that all my volumes got removed. After that my container shutdown and could not be restarted.

I tried recreating this multiple times and every time even that my container is running, the command just deletes all volumes.

Anyone can explain that behavior?

**Update:**

Following command with the container id of my MongoDB image shows me the 2 volumes:

```
docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' *CONTAINER_ID*
```

So from my understanding docker knows that these volumes and the container belong together.

When I ask docker to show me the dangling volumes, it shows me the same volumes again:

```
docker volume ls --filter dangling=true
```

So when they are dangling it makes sense to me that the prune command removes them. But I clearly have the volumes in use with my container, so that's not clear to me.

Comment: Can you include info about how you created volumes and how you are using them?

Comment: Hello,
 docker volume prune will not remove volumes that are in use by containers,
you probably have not mounted the volumes to mongodb. The fact that "docker volume ls" returns two volumes does not mean that the volumes are mounted.

Comment: @KonstantinosKatsantonis Hi, so you are saying that even when these volumes are created by default from the image and that MongoDB is working, I will still have to mount them additionally myself so that dockers know they belonged together?

Comment: Your edit makes clear that the volumes are in use by the container, Can you please share the Dockerfile you used to set up mongo?

Comment: @KonstantinosKatsantonis I actually do not have an additional dockerfile. I only took the latest image of MongoDb from docker hub and run that. Will I have to set up a dockerfile aswell? Tought that the basic image will sort these volume itself, at least that's what the documentation of the mongo image says. "Let Docker manage the storage of your database data by writing the database files to disk on the host system using its own internal volume management. This is the default and is easy and fairly transparent to the user. The downside is that the files may be hard to locate for tools...."

Comment: Could you please share the exact "docker run" command allong with the arguments you used if any ?

Comment: I have Docker installed on a Synology NAS and there it comes with a GUI. So no commands needed for basic things like starting/running a container. I started it trought the GUI from Synology DSM directly.

Comment: I have never used a GUI but the general idea is that a simple "docker run" does not mount any volumes by default. However I point out again that I am not familiar with your system.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot for your help. I'll try the process again but with mounting the volumes manually in that case.

Answer (score 15):

You can remove all existing containers then remove all volumes.

```
docker rm -vf $(docker ps -aq) && docker volume prune -f
```

---

If you want to remove only unused volumes, try

```
docker volume prune
```

or

```
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true)
```

Comment: Actually, "docker volume prune -f" forces volume removal without a prompt.

Comment: With Docker v24, `docker volume prune` will remove only unused **anonymous local volumes**. `docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true)` will do the job for **named** and unused ones.